# SML tail-recursive length-of-list function

Tags: list, sml, tail-recursion, ml

I am trying to write a tail-recursive function in Standard ML to find the length of a list; so, for example, `len([1,2,3,4,5])` should be `5`.

I was able to do it in Scheme no problem:

```
(define (len1 lis sofar)
 (if
  (null? lis) sofar
  (len1 (cdr lis) (+ sofar 1))))

(define (len lis)
 (len1 lis 0))

(len (list 2 3 4 5 6 7)) = 6
```

But I can't seem to get it in SML.  Here is what I have so far:

```
fun len [] = raise Fail "len: empty list"
 | len [x] = (x,x)
 | len (x::xs) =
```

or

```
len1([]:list, curLen:int) =  []null? then curLen | len1(tl[], curLen+1);

len([]) =  len1([], 0);
```

Comment: correction: ignore the first 3 lines listed under Sceme.  They were an attempt on SML.

Comment: If you were able to do it in Scheme, then I can only presume you don't know the syntax of SML, in which case all you have to do it read a tutorial, like this one: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/stg/NOTES/node2.html.

Comment: First write a function that isn't tail-recursive. Making it tail-recursive afterwards is very similar to how you would do it in Scheme. (Your syntax is pretty far from the ballpark, but the attempt you suggest to ignore is more SML than the second.)

Answer (score 1):

In Standard ML, you can use pattern-matching instead of an explicit `null?` check.

```ml
fun length lst = let
    fun recur [] acc = acc
           (* we don't care about the value of the element *)
      | recur (_::rest) acc = recur rest (1 + acc)
  in recur lst 0
end
```

Trying it out in the REPL gives you the expected result.

```ml
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.76 [built: Thu Feb 19 00:37:13 2015]
- fun length lst = let
    fun recur [] acc = acc
           (* we don't care about the value of the element *)
      | recur (_::rest) acc = recur rest (1 + acc)
  in recur lst 0
end ;;
- length [] ;;
= val it = 0 : int
- length [1, 2, 3] ;;
= val it = 3 : int
-
```

Agreed with the commenter to the OP, by the way. You managed fine in Scheme, which means you're probably having a bit of trouble with SML syntax. I suggest [the appropriate Learn X in Y page](http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/standard-ml/).